# Link a Flutter TextField value to a ChangeNotifier

Tags: flutter

I have a ChangeNotifier I'm using to store some state.  I have a TextField in the widget tree that I would like to be "two-way bound" to a value in the state model, meaning if the TextField is modified it updates the ChangeNotifier, or if the ChangeNotifier is updated it will reflect in the TextField.

I cannot figure out a way to do this.  Using TextField in the simple "onChanged" manner might work if it was possible to set a default value for the TextField, however the only way I see to set a value is by using a TextEditingController.  I tried that approach, adding a listener to the controller to update the state model and a listener to the state model to update the controller.text value, but this causes the cursor to reset to the front of the TextField on every update.

Comment: What you can do is that when your `TextField` is listening to the `ChangeNotifier`. Instead of updating the value of the `TextField` all the time the `ChangeNotifier` notifies its listener, only update it if the value is different than the current one in the `TextEditingController`

Comment: @ValentinVignal brilliant!  Adding the "is different" check worked like a charm, thank you.